# Use Linq to filter data from another table

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a MovieReviewsDataContext context that includes a Movie and Review table.

I would like to retrieve the top 15 movies that have at least two reviews and that have an average review better than the average movie reviews.

The code I was able to write:

```
 var topMovies = movieReviewsDataContext.Movies
                .Where(m => m.Reviews.Count > 2)
                .Where(m => m.Reviews.Average(r => r.rating) > 
                    movieReviewsDataContext.Reviews.Average(r => r.rating))
                .Take(15);
```

checks only if the average rating for the movie is higher than the global average. How do I change it to compare it to the average of all the movies' average?

Comment: Do you have a Movie property in Review entity ?

Comment: Is Reviews referenced to another table?

Comment: Review references Movie via the Movie field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a

`public virtual Movie Movie {get;set;}` property in `Review` entity

If you have not that property, you have probably something else (an `int MovieId` for example) to discriminate the review's movie, which you can use in the group by clause.

```
var averageOfMovieAverages = movieReviewsDataContext
                                         .GroupBy(x => x.Movie.Id)
                                         //.Where(x => x.Count() > 2) if you need this clause
                                         .Select(x => x.Average(m => m.rating))
                                         .Average();
```

which you can use in your query (you can also do this directly in your query, but I just created a variable for readability).